# NotificationManager/NotificationHelper not updating percentage values

Tags: android, android-notifications

So I have this class that downloads stuff... and I am implementing NotificationHelper based on [this person's example](http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/)

```
private class DatabaseStorageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            //codes here

            downloadFileCount++;
            publishProgress( (int) ((downloadFileCount/totalDownloadFileCount) * 100 ) );
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        Log.e("progressupdate", "in progressupdate");
        mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(progress[0]);
    }

}
```

This is the gist of what goes on in the code. I am unable to see whats causing my problem, as the Notification is constantly displaying 0%, even though I did a Log.e() printing of downloadFileCount and totalDownloadFileCount, which I have checked to be accurate.

Is there something I have missed out to cause the percentage progress not to be updated?

**EDIT:** Ok so I've placed Log.e() everywhere and I kinda figured out the problem but am not sure of the solution. The percentages and calculates all work fine and are giving the right numbers. However when publishProgress is invoked, the onProgressUpdate is not being called. I do not see the Log.e("progressupdate", "in progressupdate") displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works when

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    while(downloadFileCount<100){ //try while instead of for-loop


        downloadFileCount++;
        publishProgress(downloadFileCount); //only count downloadFileCount
    }
}
```

don´t know if it´s the solution, it´s just an idea....

Comment: er thanks for trying but it's totally not what i'm looking for... haha. I need to show percentages.

Comment: :) ok, sorry, not able to test it at this moment. When I am at home I will try some things if You get no solution till then....

Comment: i did a log.e of my calculations and it is all correct. but somehow it doesn't get published and I'm lost as to why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in using float rather than int values to get the percentage.

E.g. 5 of 20 = 25%

5/20 = 0.25

when using int = 0
int * 100 = 0

when using float = 0.25
float * 100 = 25

Comment: pls kindly look at my brackets properly...? (int) ((downloadFileCount/totalDownloadFileCount) * 100 ) I do the multiplication of 100 FIRST before casting to int. Wouldn't that prevent such things from happening?

Comment: Check the example here :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html